# Rewrite not working, even though AllowOverride is set to All

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I've installed LAMP stack on a digitalocean droplet running on Ubuntu. I have a file called "/restful/post.php".

using "https://url/restful/post.php" works just fine, however, I want to make it SEO friendly, sth like "/restful/post".

my htaccess is in the root folder "html/var/www" and has the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/restful/post(.*)$ /restful/post.php?p=$1
```

I have got a2enmode enabled, AllowOverride is set to All in "/etc/sites-available/*".

for the 000-default.conf, I've got:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        Redirect / https:/url
        <Directory /var/www/html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Allow from All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and for the 000-default-le-ssl.conf, I've got:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        <Directory /var/www/html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Allow from All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

All the answers to the questions I've seen didn't fix my issue and I'm not really sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: When configured on the .htaccess level, the path RewriteRule matches against _never_ starts with a leading slash, that has been stripped off at that point already.

Comment: (And with that kind of overlap between the “fake” URL and real existing file name, you might want to disable `MultiViews` as well, otherwise that easily leads into trouble in these kind of situations.)